# Is it possible to use a variable as code in python

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Almost 20 yrs ago when I learned perl, I remember **you could us a variable as code**.  I am not sure why this isnt working so ***I would love to know if "interpolating a variable can become code" in python.***

for instance:

```
def count_usages():

    fields_ls = ['reporter', 'creator', 'assignee', 'duedate']

    counts = {}

    for field in fields_ls:
        null_crit = field + "__isnull=True"
        blank_crit = field + "__exact=''"

        counts[field] = Ticket.objects.exclude(null_crit).exclude(blank_crit).count()


    for key, value in counts.iteritems():
        print "## - for " + key + " we had " + value
```

At some level I think Python is "compiled" so I am guessing a runtime evaluation like this wont work but I'd love to know for sure.

Pls advise.  Thank you!

Comment: please post your error traceback. I'm even not sure what you want to do. Maybe you need eval()?

Comment: You can do this using either the `locals()` dictionary or the `globals()` dictionary (depending on the preferred scope). But I would strongly recommend against using it like that, it's bad design and prone to breaking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you would never ever want to do this. Always use a dictionary.

```
for field in fields_ls:
    null_crit = {field + "__isnull": True}
    blank_crit = {field + "__exact": ''}

    counts[field] = Ticket.objects.exclude(**null_crit).exclude(**blank_crit).count()
```

(Python's refusal to do this has nothing to do with it being "compiled"; it is exactly as compiled as Perl.)

Answer (score 2):

See it works this way;

```
name = "False"
if name:
  print(name)
```

Outputs `'False'` because `name` is non-empty `str` so it evaluates to `True`.

```
if eval(name):
  print(name)
else:
  print('no')
```

Outputs `'no'` because `name`s content has been evaluated in the context of currnet globals and locals.

But assignments don't work winth `eval` because in Python assignment is not an expression and `eval` needs an expression.

This is an error with `eval`;

```
s = "name=True"
eval(s)
```

To execute statements in a string, you have to use `exec`.

```
s = "name=True"
exec(s)
```

Now `name` is defined to be of type `bool` with value `True`.